# retrieve current user meta data (custom fields included)

Tags: functions

I use "User Registration" plugin to create a registration form. Once the user has registered and logged in, I need to retrieve inside "Function.php" all his data that he completed in the registration form. I already tested `wp_get_current_user()` but it only return default fields...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried `get_user_meta($user_id, $key, $single);`?

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_user_meta

Comment: thank you, I used the function this way: get_user_meta( get_current_user_id(), 'XXXXX', true );